# gazebo_ros_bumper_controller not updating bumper states

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been implementing this code. I am trying to echo the Contact messages but states does not echo any value even if it undergoes collision.Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong

```
<gazebo reference="base">
<sensor name="main_bumper" type="contact">
<geom>base_geom</geom>
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
    <contact>
       <collision name="bump_sensor_collision_collision"></collision>
    </contact>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_bumper_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">   
        <bumperTopicName>bumper_vals</bumperTopicName>
        <frameName>world</frameName>
    </plugin>
</sensor>
</gazebo>

</robot>
```

This is the output that I am getting :

```
header: 
  seq: 89604
  stamp: 
    secs: 584
    nsecs: 451000000
  frame_id: world
states: []
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277175/gazebo_ros_bumper_controller-not-updating-bumper-states/) by [Als177](https://answers.ros.org/users/32846/als177/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-12-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-03**:
I edited your question to make it more readable (using the preformatted text, or `101010` button) and moved your title to the body of the question, and gave it a more meaningful (to me) title...

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-03**:
Feel free to edit it but please keep in mind that having a short and direct title may help you get more people reading your question.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-28**:
If the bumper topic isn't even publishing it's worth looking at `~/.gazebo/server-11345/gzserver.log`, it may give clues that fields inside `<sensor>` are wrong for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem is that you do not have a match between the collision name in base and the collision name in contact.
Generate the sdf file with

```
gz sdf -p <your_filename>.urdf
```

and see if they match.  The name generated in the sdf is a strange one. I see that you already discovered that it adds an extra "_collision" at the end. In my urdf files it puts other things into the name as well.

Also, I found that this did not work for me:

```
<collision name="bump_sensor_collision_collision"></collision>
```

I had to use this format (as well as getting the name right, of course):

```
<collision>bump_sensor_collision_collision</collision>
```

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mrudul](https://answers.ros.org/users/35835/mrudul/) on 2018-07-08**:
Hii, can you please explain what should be typed in the collision line.